# Python concurrency - t1.start() TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing

I got this question in a technical interview recently:

**Print series 010203040506. Using multi-threading, the 1st thread will print only 0, the 2nd thread will print only even numbers, and 3rd thread print only odd numbers.**

While I've some experience in Python, I've never really written any multithreaded code. So after reading some documentation, I've managed to create the class that will do the job. I'm trying to put things together, but not really sure how to go about it. Can someone help me with a lock or semaphore based solution for this?

```
  import threading


class PrintSeries(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, start, stop, step, string):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.string = string
        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop
        self.step = step

    def run(self):
        if self.start < self.stop:
            self.start += self.step
        self.string += str(self.start)
s = ''
t1 = PrintSeries(0, 0, 0, s)
t2 = PrintSeries(1, 2, 5, s)
t3 = PrintSeries(2, 2, 6, s)

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()
print(s)
```

In any case, even this runs into the following error,

`t1.start()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [condition](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#condition-objects) objects

> The typical programming style using condition variables uses the lock
>   to synchronize access to some shared state; threads that are
>   interested in a particular change of state call wait() repeatedly
>   until they see the desired state, while threads that modify the state
>   call notify() or notifyAll() when they change the state in such a way
>   that it could possibly be a desired state for one of the waiters

The expected execution sequence is (t1, t3, t1, t2, t1, t3, ...) so we just create a state variable holding the current state and every thread would only work if the expected condition is met. After that it would update the state and awake the other threads

```
from threading import Thread, Lock, Condition


def zero_printer(max_iters):
    global state
    for _ in range(max_iters):
        with cv:
            while state not in (0, 2):
                cv.wait()
            state += 1
            print('0')
            cv.notify_all()


def even_printer(max_iters):
    global state
    c = 2
    for _ in range(max_iters):
        with cv:
            while state != 3:
                cv.wait()
            print(c)
            state = 0
            cv.notify_all()
        c += 2


def odd_printer(max_iters):
    global state
    c = 1
    for _ in range(max_iters):
        with cv:
            while state != 1:
                cv.wait()
            print(c)
            state = 2
            cv.notify_all()
        c += 2


iters = 3
state = 0
cv = Condition(Lock())

t1 = Thread(target=zero_printer, args=(iters * 2,))
t2 = Thread(target=even_printer, args=(iters,))
t3 = Thread(target=odd_printer, args=(iters,))

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()
```

The outcome:

```
0
1
0
2
0
3
0
4
0
5
0
6
```

I didn't bother combining it into a single line.

The error in your code was that you're misusing the `threading.Thread` [constructor](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) namely passing an integer value as the expectet *target* argument so it tried to execute your *int* value and produced the respective error message